# Angular Safe Navigation Operator, Dynamic Properties and Bracket Notation

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Angular 2 has a '[safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator)' that allows template references to potentially undefined child properties in your components.

Is there any way to use this with dynamic properties and bracket notation? e.g.,

```
<input [type]="text" [ngModel]="formValues?[control]">
```

Where `control` is another variable from my component telling the template which form value to use and formValues is loaded async so could potentially be null.

Comment: This is basically nothing to go on, please share more code so we can help :)

Comment: @AJT_82, thanks for commenting.  The code in question doesn't really matter it's more of a generic technique.  Angular 1 was null safe for template references.  Rather than use that behavior Angular 2 has the 'safe navigation operator'.  But is there a way to use that with variable property names?  I feel like I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: Asked because since not knowing what `formValues?[control]` is supposed to REALLY do or contains. So hard to say if it could work. Something like `someObj?.someProperty` I do understand what is doing exactly. Hmm, might *ngIf work for you in this case, to check that there is value before rendering? `<input *ngIf="formValues[control]" ... />` as said, not really knowing what is going on with that, hard to help further.

Comment: @AJT_82, here's a plnk https://plnkr.co/edit/TeGqrnZJA9zADN6NhYzB?p=preview

I figured ngIf might be the only way.  Makes the safe navigation operator kind of a poor replacement for the way Ng1 handled this :)  (though it's better in lots of other ways)

Comment: Thanks for plunker. With this it seems to work fine with the ngIf, was this something you were looking for? https://plnkr.co/edit/KGD9QP4IZyA2CshehMrr?p=preview

Comment: I don't think you can solve this with the safe navigation operator... But if someone can prove me wrong I'd be more than happy!

Comment: Yep.  Just feels clunky to have to add an ngIf to every element that has a reference of this type rather than the shiny new operator :)

Comment: Yeah sure, I understand that completely! `?` operator is nicer ;) But whatever your code is, you can of course wrap the whole thingie around the ngIf and not each element. But if they are scattered of course this is a clunky mess...

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can't, but this is what I'm using, simpler than ngif but empty string and 0 will not do what is after the `&&` :

```
<input [type]="text" [ngModel]="formValues && formValues[control]">
```

Comment: in TS you can to formValues?.[control] but angular does not allow this as of now